# Clarification of existential statement needed.

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

I am currently working my way through The Book of Proof and I need a little help understanding this conjecture:

Suppose $ f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 +...+ a_nx^n $ is a polynomial of degree 1 or greater, and for which each coefficient $ a_i $ is in $ \mathbb{N} $.
Then there is a $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ for which the integer $ f(k) $ is not prime.

I am almost afraid to ask this, but how do I know how big $ n $ is?
If $ n $ had a fixed value, giving an example would suffice as proof for this existential statement, right?
Am I supposed to proof that there is a $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ for which every $ f(k) $ is not prime, no matter how big $ n $ is?

Comment: The way the question is put, you have to prove it for all $n\in \Bbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\cdots \}$. For e.g if $a_0\ne 1$, $f(a_0)$ is divisible by $a_0$ and greater than $a_0$, since all the coefficients are positive, hence it is not prime. So yes, "... no matter how big $n$ is"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $n$ is not quantified in the statement, it is universally quantified.

> (For all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ with $n \geq 1$...)  Suppose $ f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 +...+ a_nx^n $ is a polynomial of degree 1 or greater, and for which each coefficient $ a_i $ is in $ \mathbb{N} $.
> Then there is a $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ for which the integer $ f(k) $ is not prime.

For existence, you need a prescription that produces a $k$.  Your prescription for $k$ is permitted to depend on $n$ and all the $a_i$.

It turns out you can find a prescription for $k$ that does not (really) depend on $n$.  (Any use of all of the $a_i$ will use $n$ as a bound, but we could establish the set $A = \{a_i : 0\leq i \leq n\}$ and then only use $A$, subsequently.)